# How to tell outlook 2013 where to pick up certificates for exchange 2013?

Tags: exchange, certificate, outlook

We got new exchange 2013 server in place and using OWA for long time. now we are trying to push outlook 2013 application to all users. Some of users can run outlook 2013 app without any issue. Some of users get errors saying that

1. "can't connect to exchange server, server must be online".
2. When user create an outlook profile on local PC, it always pickup the certificate from our old exchange server. Is there a way to tell outlook where to pick up the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You install your certificates on the server that holds the Client Access Service role, when clients connect to the CAS they will use it when Outlook is configured.

How many Exchange servers do you have in the environment?